# How to use expression in regex -replace with capturing group in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-group

I want to replace octal codes with the ascii character equivalents in a string.

Input example: `\052.test.com`

I've tried all sorts of different combinations, but why doesn't this work, and how do I fix it?

```
> "\052.test.com" -replace '\\(0[1-7][0-7])', "`$1"
052.test.com

> "\052.test.com" -replace '\\(0[1-7][0-7])', [char][convert]::ToInt32("052", 8)
*.test.com

> "\052.test.com" -replace '\\(0[1-7][0-7])', [char][convert]::ToInt32("`$1", 8)
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ToInt32" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find any recognizable digits."
```

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows PowerShell, the second right-hand argument to `-replace` will be evaluated like any other expression, and the resulting argument value treated **as a string** *no matter what you pass to it*.

To invoke a callback function against each match, you can use `[regex]::Replace(...)`, and pass a scriptblock in place of the substitution string - the runtime will pass a `MatchInfo` object as the first argument to the scriptblock, from where you can extract the capture groups value:

```
[regex]::Replace("\052.test.com", '\\0([0-7][0-7])', {
  $matchInfo = $args[0]
  [convert]::ToInt32($matchInfo.Groups[1].Value, 8) -as [char]
})
```

In PowerShell 6.2+ and 7 you can pass the scriptblock directly as an operand to `-replace` - the `MatchInfo` result will be bound to `$_` automatically:

```
"\052.test.com" -replace '\\0([0-7][0-7])', {
  [convert]::ToInt32($_.Groups[1].Value, 8) -as [char]
}
```

Comment: Since the octal digits can be up to `377`, should the pattern be `'\\0([0-7]*)'`? It appears that the `Replace()` function sets `$Matches`, but the `-replace` operator does not. Is that correct?

Comment: @lit I assume OP expects only `\0XX`  (ie. 6-bit) values based on the original question (you'll notice they use `\\0` as the prefix in the example) - but yes, if you're expecting larger numbers you'd indeed need to make such a change

Comment: Perhaps the regex should be `'\\0([0-7]{1,3})'` if all octal values could be used.